# Why would we need to know $c_p - c_v$

Tags: thermodynamics

I understand that it's easier to calculate $c_p$ experimentally since we pretty much experience  constant pressure conditions all our lives. It's also more difficult to calculate $c_p$ mathematically since $$c_p = \Bigg{(}\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial T}\Bigg{)}_p$$ Mathematically $$c_v= \Bigg{(}\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial T}\Bigg{)}_V$$Is easier to calculate, But I've just proved $c_p - c_v$ and it took me a while so I was wondering why would we need to know $$c_p-c_v = \Bigg{[}p + \Bigg{(}\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial V}\Bigg{)}_T\Bigg{]}\Bigg{(}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}\Bigg{)}_p$$

Basically why would we need to know $c_p - c_v$ at all.

Comment: As is not uncommon there's [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212734/relation-between-heat-capacities?rq=1) from @John-Rennie that gives some physical insight to the significance of $c_p - c_v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the heat capacities is the [definition of the specific gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant#Specific_gas_constant):

$$ R_{\text{specific}} = c_p - c_v $$

And so depending on your use-case, that could be handy. Usually we use it the other way around to get either $c_p$ or $c_v$ from the universal gas constant and molecular weight and whichever heat capacity we know.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the quantity $c_p-c_v$, where $c_p$ is the specific heat for a constant pressure and $c_v$ is the specific heat for a constant volume, is given by the Mayer Relation that relates the specific gas constant to the specific heats for a *calorically perfect gas* and a *thermally perfect gas*.

### Generalizations

*For more general homogeneous substances*, not just ideal gases, the difference takes the form,

$$ C_{P}-C_{V}=VT\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\beta_{T}},$$
where $C_{P}$ is the heat capacity of a body at constant pressure, $C_{V}$ is the heat capacity at constant volume, $V$ is the volume, $T$ is the temperature, $\alpha _{T}$  is the thermal expansion coefficient and $\beta$  is the isothermal compressibility.

From this relation, several inferences can be made:

- Since isothermal compressibility $\beta _{T}$ is positive for all phases and the square of thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$ is a positive quantity or zero, the specific heat at constant-pressure is always greater than or equal to specific heat at constant-volume.
  $$C_{{P,m}} \geq C_{V,m}$$
- As the absolute temperature of the system approaches zero, the difference between $C_{P,m}$ and $C_{V,m}$ also approaches zero.
- For incompressible substances, $C_{P,m}$ and $C_{V,m}$ are identical. Also for substances that are nearly incompressible, such as solids and liquids, the difference between the two specific heats is negligible.